# How to implement boundedBuffer using Monitor in C#?

Tags: c#

I come form Java world, and I know we could implement a boundedBuffer using Monitor + 2 conditional variables.

How to implement this in C#? I checked , it seems that C# does not support conditional variable?

Comment: Probably by using `ManualResetEvent` instead of `Condition`

Comment: Is this a single producer/single consumer situation, or are there many producers/consumers?

Comment: The Monitor class implements the behavior of a condition variable.  Just don't, use the BlockingCollection class.

Comment: @Hans I know Monitor implements  a condition variable, but in this case,we need two conditional variables for represent full/empty

Comment: @Brandon, it is many producers/consumers, multiple threads

Comment: @xanatos, can multiple threads wait for a single event?

Comment: @HansPassant's point was that the BlockingCollection is a built in implementation of a bounded buffer.  So why do you need to create your own?